# dealing with object property access in js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

here is how my js look like

```
$scope.tasks = [
    {
    "name":"task 1",
    "date":"2 May 2014"
    },

    {"name":"task 2",
    "date":"2 May 2014"
    }
];
```

html

```
<ul ng-repeat="task in tasks">
    <li>{{task.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

I want to try to avoid `{{task.name}}` to keep my markup cleaner. I tried `$scope.tasks = $scope.tasks.name;` in `JS`, but it's not working.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid that? Why do you think it will make your markup cleaner? Surely this change means complicating the code elsewhere.

Comment: @Joe as you can see I have to type task.name in my markup. It would be nice if it's just task. and I wish in my js I can make tasks = tasks.name.

Comment: "It would just be nice" is sometimes a good reason but very rarely. If it means complicating your code elsewhere, then it's a bad idea. IMHO. Your logic is "iterate over tasks and show the name of each", and your current code is the cleanest way to express it.

Comment: I have added an answer showing how do to this. It answers your question about how to do it, and also shows that it doesn't look very nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to do it.

In your controller you need to watch for changes:

```
// Run whenever tasks changes.
$scope.$watch("tasks", function(tasks) {
  // Tasks may be be undefined or nil.
  if (tasks) {
    // Map the array to pick out the titles.
    $scope.taskTitles = tasks.map(function(task) { return task.title })
  }
}
```

If you don't do this, your list won't update whenever the tasks change. This 'watching' is a fundamental part of Angular.

Then in your templates you need to iterate.

```
<ul ng-repeat="task in taskTitles track by $index">
    <li>{{task}}</li>
</ul>
```

If there's a chance your titles will be duplicate you need the `track by`.

So you can do it, but it's not cleaner. I recommend you stick with what you have.

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.tasks = [
    {
    "name":"task 1",
    "date":"2 May 2014"
    },

    {"name":"task 2",
    "date":"2 May 2014"
    }
];

var temp = [];

for(var task in $scope.tasks){
    temp.push(task.name);
}

$scope.tasks = temp;
```

<strike>This will do what you want. However, it will aso overwrite your original object</strike>

I think you are overcomplicating things and having hard times wrapping your head around the basic concepts of Angular.

Personally, i even believe that this would make things worse. In your `ng-repeat`, you are telling Angular that it should list each `task` in `tasks`. Then, it should show the name of each task. That is obviously the tasks name aka `task.name`. By omitting the term `task`, your code would be harder to read, as you can't see *which* name is meant.

Comment: No it won't. It breaks the template observing changes to `tasks`.

Comment: What @Joe says is correct of course. I forgot to mention that you would have to apply further changes in order to get this to work, obviously, as your ng-repeat relies on the original object